# Split my schema.graphql into multiple files in Amplify

Tags: angular, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm working with Amplify and I'd like to split all my schema.graphql code into different files cause It bugs me to have that much code in one file.
As well, I'd like that when I push my changes, the code generated in my API.service.ts splits into multiple files, is this possible?

I tried with adding #import to my schema.graphql file (and then import the code from other graphql files) but it looks like the "#" comments the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To split you schema into multiple files, you can replace the `schema.graphql` with a folder named `schema` and put multiple `*.graphql` into it. Amplify will merge all these files into one schema file.

That's an example from my project:

[image]

The `root.graphql` file contains the root `Query` and `Mutation` type. Be aware that you cannot have multiple root types, you must place all custom queries and mutations inside this file. I think naming the file `root` doesn't matter though.

The TypeScript type generation is configured by the `.graphqlconfig.yml` file. The file defines a project with a `schemaPath` property which must point to the merged schema file inside `/build` folder:

```yaml
projects:
  my-project:
    # points to the compiled schema
    schemaPath: amplify/backend/api/graphql/build/schema.graphql
    includes:
      - src/graphql/**/*.ts
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        codeGenTarget: typescript
        generatedFileName: src/API.ts
        docsFilePath: src/graphql
        region: eu-west-1
        apiId: null
        maxDepth: 2
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```

You could try if it is possible to configure multiple projects, each pointing towards a different single `/schema/*.graphql` file instead of the compiled schema. But I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: Does splitting the schema files help with build time and errors.  I dread modifying my schema because it barely ever completes a push.

Comment: I don't think so. In the end, it gets compiled into one single `schema.graphql` and pushed to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Zirkelc's answer is correct, however there have been continuous issues reported with this functionality, documented here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/1074

As of this comment, the most recent version of Amplify CLI (12.1.1) fixes the issue.